Почему в span передается текст только после второго нажатия на button"редактировать"?
1)нажимаю кнопку "редактировать"
2)Ввожу текст
3)убираю фокус
4)span пустой
Но если я нажму опять кнопку "редактировать" и уберу фокус с textarea, то текст сохраняется
как сделать что бы сохранялся сразу после ухода фокуса?
код в в скрипте подписан, как (//редактирование текста)


body {
  background-color: #fbf2e9;
}

.group-btn {
  margin         : 1em;
  display        : flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap            : 1em;
}

.text-window {
  color      : aliceblue;
  user-select: none;
}

button {
  user-select: none;
}

input {
  user-select: none;
}

.blockDnone {
  display: none;
}

.block {
  position        : absolute;
  top             : 0;
  left            : 0;
  width           : 100%;
  height          : 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity         : 0.9;
}

.block2 {
  width          : 100%;
  height         : 100%;
  display        : flex;
  flex-direction : column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items    : center;
}

.closeWindow {
  width      : 5vw;
  height     : 5vh;
  font-weight: 900;
  color      : black;
}

.groupTextAll {
  margin: 1em 0em;
}


.group {
  margin       : 1em;
  padding      : .5em 1em;
  border       : 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 1em;
}


.text {
  color: gray;
}

.subject-btn {
  display        : flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.edit {
  display: none;
}



textarea {
  background-color: bisque;
  width           : 100%;
  height          : 150px;
  resize          : none;
}


.none {
  display: none;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="news.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body id="all">
    <div class="groupTextAll">
      <div class="group-btn">
        <button class="delAll">Удалить все</button>
        <button class="add">Добавить новость</button>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <div class="subject-btn">
          <button class="very">Редактировать</button>
          <button class="del">удалить</button>
        </div>
        <h2 class="vi">
          Муфтий призвал наказать блогера, который растоптал и оплевал
          православный крест
        </h2>
        <span class="text view">
          Глумившегося над православным крестом блогера из Дагестана необходимо
          строго наказать по российскому законодательству, заявил РИА Новости
          председатель Координационного центра мусульман Северного Кавказа
          муфтий Исмаил Бердиев.РИА Новости Исмаил Бердиев Ранее с просьбой
          привлечь блогера к ответственности в МВД и Генпрокуратуру обратился
          глава комитета Госдумы по информполитике Александр Хинштейн.Телеканал
          360° 17 июля в сети появилось видео, на котором дагестанский стример
          топчет ногами православный крест.Lenta.ru Следственный комитет
          возбудил уголовное дело по ч. 1 ст. 148 Уголовного кодекса — нарушение
          права на свободу совести и вероисповеданий.
        </span>
        <textarea name="text" class="edits edit"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <div class="subject-btn">
          <button class="very">Редактировать</button>
          <button class="del">удалить</button>
        </div>
        <h2 class="vi">
          Лавров обратился к постпреду США в СБ ООН и спросил, не ошиблась ли
          она комнатой
        </h2>
        <span class="text view">
          Министр иностранных дел РФ Сергей Лавров, выступая в ходе заседания
          Совбеза ООН, посвященного кризису на Ближнем Востоке, обратился к
          постпреду США Линде Томас-Гринфилд.РИА Новости Поводом для такого
          обращения послужило выступление постпреда США на предыдущем заседании
          Совбеза ООН, организованном Россией и посвященном многостороннему
          сотрудничеству, где Гринфилд сосредоточила внимание на украинском
          кризисе.URA.Ru «Слушая сегодня представителя Израиля, у вас не
          возникло ощущение, что вы ошиблись комнатой и пришли не на ту
          дискуссию, которая была объявлена? Надеюсь, понятно, о чем я говорю»,
          — обратился Лавров к Гринфилд (цитата по ТАСС).РБК Сегодня постпред
          Израиля, который ранее выступил на дебатах в Совбезе по
          ближневосточному кризису, активно критиковал Иран и заявил, что
          Тегеран "поставляет военное оборудование, которое потом используется
          против украинцев".РИА Новости
        </span>
        <textarea name="text" class="edits edit"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <div class="subject-btn">
          <button class="very">Редактировать</button>
          <button class="del">удалить</button>
        </div>
        <h2 class="vi">
          Путин поручил перейти к масштабному внедрению цифрового рубля
        </h2>
        <span class="text view">
          Платформа цифрового рубля продемонстрировала свою
          работоспособность.Газета.Ru России необходимо не упустить момент —
          своевременно настраивать правовую базу, развивать инфраструктуру,
          создавать условия для обращения цифровых активов как внутри страны,
          так и в отношениях с зарубежными партнерами, заявил Путин.ТВ Центр
          "Нужно сделать следующий шаг: перейти к более широкому внедрению
          цифрового рубля в экономику, хозяйственную деятельность и в сферу
          финансов", — отметил Путин.Газета.Ru Банк России с 1 сентября расширит
          пилот цифрового рубля на реальных клиентах с реальными деньгами,
          сообщила первый зампред ЦБ Ольга Скоробогатова на Финансовом
          конгрессе.
        </span>
        <textarea name="text" class="edits edit"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      "use strict";
      //удаление контента
      $("button.delAll").click(() => $("div.group").remove());

      //удаление по одной
      $("div.groupTextAll").click((event) => {
        const btn = $(event.target);
        if (!btn.is('button.del')) return;
        $(event.target).closest('div.group').remove()
      });

      //добавление контента
      $("button.add").click(() => {
        $('<div class="group"><div class="subject-btn"><button class="very">Редактировать</button><button class="del">удалить</button></div><h2 class="vi">Заголовок</h2><span class="text view">Текст</span><textarea name="text" class="edits edit"></textarea></div>').appendTo("div.groupTextAll");
      });
        //редактирование текста
        
      $('div.groupTextAll').click((event)=>{

        const $parent = $(event.target).closest("div.group"),
        very = $(event.target);
        if(!very.is('button.very')) return;
          $parent.find('span.view').addClass('none');
          $parent.find('textarea.edits').removeClass('edit');
         let textarea = $parent.find('textarea.edits').val();
         let span = $parent.find('span.view').text(textarea);
         
      });

   
      $('textarea.edit').on('blur',(event)=>{
          // if(event.key == 'Enter') $('textarea.edits').blur();
            $('span.view').removeClass('none');
            $('textarea.edits').addClass('edit');
         });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>




немного улучшил код, сделав обращение кнопки "редактировать" к каждому "span"

Немного помучился и сделал:


body {
  background-color: #fbf2e9;
}

.group-btn {
  margin         : 1em;
  display        : flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap            : 1em;
}

.text-window {
  color      : aliceblue;
  user-select: none;
}

button {
  user-select: none;
}

input {
  user-select: none;
}

.blockDnone {
  display: none;
}

.block {
  position        : absolute;
  top             : 0;
  left            : 0;
  width           : 100%;
  height          : 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity         : 0.9;
}

.block2 {
  width          : 100%;
  height         : 100%;
  display        : flex;
  flex-direction : column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items    : center;
}

.closeWindow {
  width      : 5vw;
  height     : 5vh;
  font-weight: 900;
  color      : black;
}

.groupTextAll {
  margin: 1em 0em;
}


.group {
  margin       : 1em;
  padding      : .5em 1em;
  border       : 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 1em;
}


.text {
  color: gray;
}

.subject-btn {
  display        : flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.edit {
  display: none;
}



textarea {
  background-color: bisque;
  width           : 100%;
  height          : 150px;
  resize          : none;
}


.none {
  display: none;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="news.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body id="all">
    <div class="groupTextAll">
      <div class="group-btn">
        <button class="delAll">Удалить все</button>
        <button class="add">Добавить новость</button>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <div class="subject-btn">
          <button class="very">Редактировать</button>
          <button class="del">удалить</button>
        </div>
        <h2 class="vi">
          Муфтий призвал наказать блогера, который растоптал и оплевал
          банковский пластик
        </h2>
        <span class="text view">
          Глумившегося над банковским пластиком блогера из Дагестана необходимо
          строго наказать по российскому законодательству, заявил РИА Новости
          председатель Координационного центра мусульман Северного Кавказа
          муфтий Исмаил Бердиев.РИА Новости Исмаил Бердиев Ранее с просьбой
          привлечь блогера к ответственности в МВД и Генпрокуратуру обратился
          глава комитета Госдумы по информполитике Александр Хинштейн.Телеканал
          360° 17 июля в сети появилось видео, на котором дагестанский стример
          топчет ногами банковский пластик.Lenta.ru Следственный комитет
          возбудил уголовное дело по ч. 1 ст. 148 Уголовного кодекса — нарушение
          права на свободу предпринимательства.
        </span>
        <textarea name="text" class="edits edit"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <div class="subject-btn">
          <button class="very">Редактировать</button>
          <button class="del">удалить</button>
        </div>
        <h2 class="vi">
          Лавров обратился к постпреду США в СБ ООН и спросил, не ошиблась ли
          она планетой
        </h2>
        <span class="text view">
          Министр иностранных дел РФ Сергей Лавров, выступая в ходе заседания
          Совбеза ООН, посвященного кризису на Ближнем Востоке, обратился к
          постпреду США Линде Томас-Гринфилд.РИА Новости Поводом для такого
          обращения послужило выступление постпреда США на предыдущем заседании
          Совбеза ООН, организованном Россией и посвященном многостороннему
          сотрудничеству, где Гринфилд сосредоточила внимание на марсианском
          кризисе.URA.Ru «Слушая сегодня представителя Израиля, у вас не
          возникло ощущение, что вы ошиблись планетой и прилетели не на ту
          дискуссию, которая была объявлена? Надеюсь, понятно, о чем я говорю»,
          — обратился Лавров к Гринфилд (цитата по ТАСС).РБК Сегодня постпред
          Израиля, который ранее выступил на дебатах в Совбезе по
          ближневосточному кризису, активно критиковал Луну и заявил, что
          Коперник-Сити "поставляет военное оборудование, которое потом используется
          против марсиан".РИА Новости
        </span>
        <textarea name="text" class="edits edit"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <div class="subject-btn">
          <button class="very">Редактировать</button>
          <button class="del">удалить</button>
        </div>
        <h2 class="vi">
          Путин поручил перейти к масштабному внедрению цифрового замка
        </h2>
        <span class="text view">
          Платформа цифрового замка продемонстрировала свою
          работоспособность.Газета.Ru России необходимо не упустить момент —
          своевременно настраивать правовую базу, развивать инфраструктуру,
          создавать условия для обращения цифровых запоров как внутри страны,
          так и в отношениях с зарубежными партнерами, заявил Путин.ТВ Центр
          "Нужно сделать следующий шаг: перейти к более широкому внедрению
          цифрового замка в экономику, хозяйственную деятельность и в сферу
          охраны", — отметил Путин.Газета.Ru Банк России с 1 сентября расширит
          пилот цифрового замка на реальных воротах с реальными петлями,
          сообщила первый зампред ЦБ Ольга Скоробогатова на Охранном
          конгрессе.
        </span>
        <textarea name="text" class="edits edit"></textarea>
      </div>
      <template class="creat">
        <div class="group">
          <div class="subject-btn">
            <button class="very">Редактировать</button>
            <button class="del">удалить</button>
          </div>
          <h2 class="vi">Заголовок</h2>
          <span class="text view"> Текст </span>
          <textarea name="text" class="edits edit"></textarea>
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      "use strict";
      //удаление контента
      $("button.delAll").click(() => $("div.group").remove());

      //удаление по одной
      $("div.groupTextAll").click((event) => {
        const btn = $(event.target);
        if (!btn.is("button.del")) return;
        $(event.target).closest("div.group").remove();
      });

      //редактирование текста

      $("div.groupTextAll").click((event) => {
        const $parent = $(event.target).closest("div.group"),
          very = $(event.target);
        if (!very.is("button.very")) return;
        const span = $parent.find("span.view");
        const textarea = $parent.find("textarea.edits");
        span.addClass("none");
        textarea.removeClass("edit");
        textarea.focus();

        textarea.blur((event) => {
          span.text(textarea.val());
          span.removeClass("none");
          textarea.addClass("edit");
        });
        textarea.keydown((event) => {
          if (event.key == "Enter") $parent.find("textarea.edits").blur();
        });
      });

      //добавление контента
      $("div.groupTextAll").click((event) => {
        let $target = $(event.target).closest("div.groupTextAll");
        let addBtn = $(event.target);
        let $clone = $target.find("template.creat").clone();
        if (!addBtn.is("button.add")) return;
        $("div.groupTextAll").append($clone.html());
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>




я переделал, теперь это полноценный 100% ответ, все четко функционирует
